# How to make an inline-block box stick to the top?

Tags: html, css, layout

I try to make the **blue** container stick to the top. How can I manage that?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="a">blue</div>
    <div class="b">green</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.a {
    width:100px;
    height:400px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:blue;
}
.b {
    width:400px;
    height:600px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: green;
}
.container {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xswa4/

```
vertical-align: top;
```

doesn't work...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use [`vertical-align:top;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) on the element `.a` itself, not the parent `.container`:

```css
.a {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:blue;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/xswa4/5/)**

Comment: It worked fine! Thank you! Just one more question: why does the green box move up when I apply the vertical-align on the blue one?

Comment: @maximilian009 I'm testing in Chrome 32 on Windows 7, but I don't see this issue on the fiddle demo.

Comment: I'm not having any issues. I dont understand why the blue box moves up when I apply vertical-align-top to the green box. Wouldnt it be logical that the blue box moves up when I apply the style to the blue box and the green one moves up when I apply it to the green one?

Comment: @maximilian009 In fact, in that case the `blue` box is still **[aligned vertically in its `baseline`](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/xswa4/6/)**. The point is that the larger box (the green one) stretches the *parent* and affects the visual alignment of the other `inline(-block)` elements.

Answer (score 1):

Your `vertical-align` needs to be on the blue container, not the parent container.

```
.a
{
    width:100px;
    height:400px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:blue;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xswa4/3/

Answer (score 1):

Answer to Original Question:

When you specify `vertical-align: top` The top of the element is aligned with the top of the tallest element `on the line`. In your case, the `div` siblings `a and b are on the line` within the parent div `container`. So, the logical place to give the vertical-alignment is at the `div sibling` level.

Answer to your comment question:

`I don't understand why the blue box moves up when I apply vertical-align-top to the green box.`

If the `vertical-align: top` property is applied to the tallest element on the line, then the sibling which in your case is `div a` would align to the tallest. 
If you want to explore more take a look at the [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/kirtithorat/BXLn3/1/).

Look how `a`,`b`,`c`,`d` and `e` are aligned when I set the `vertical-align: top` property on the `c div` which is the tallest one. In this case, within siblings `divs a, b, d and e`, `d` is the tallest so it gets aligned to the tallest element i.e. `c` but `a`,`b` and `e` are aligned to the horizontal baseline of `d` who is the next tallest.

Answer (score 0):

Better way to do it.

```
.container{position:relative;}
.a {position:absolute;top:0;}
```

Im surprised no one has mentioned absolute positioning.

Comment: VERTICAL ALIGN IS USED FOR TABLES

Comment: ...and inline or inline-block elements :). Why are you shouting?

Comment: `Im surprised no one has mentioned absolute positioning` Because by using absolute positioning, the elements would be removed from document normal flow and the container wouldn't have any idea about the absolute positioned elements to adjust its height. Also, IMO changing the whole logic may cause trouble for the OP. Sincerely.